# Google Chrome automatically clears my Downloads page

Tags: google-chrome, download

On both Windows and Arch Linux, I find that when a download completes in Chrome, it disappears from the downloads page and from the downloads bar at the bottom of my browser window.

Pray, how can I keep my completed downloads from disappearing from the browser?

Comment: Do you mean if you press CTRL+J, you don't see any of your downloads? *Personally, I don't know why you're complaining: I have to manually open that page and clear my downloads every time. I wish there a way to change that

Comment: create a new user profile on chrome and try downloading files....and see if the download list is still there...

Comment: @InterLinked : Yes, I pres CTRL+J to go to the downloads page. The list is empty.

Comment: This sounds like an extension you have installed. Can you confirm you don't have an extension that is clearing the list?

Comment: @JellicleCat Glad it's solved! I've added an answer, modify it to add any extra details if you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments on the question, user has an extension installed in Chrome that is clearing the downloads list on an automated interval.

Removing or disabling this extension will resolve this issue for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://downloads/`. There, you will find in time order all your downloads. If you still can't find it there, click on `Open downloads folder`.

Comment: At least that is how it works for me. Could you make your question a little more specific?

Comment: I have been going there, but the list is empty as soon as my downloads complete. And my intention is to avoid actually needing to open the downloads folder.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the confusion.